# Angular2 subscribe inside subscribe

Tags: angular, angular2-services

In Angular2, what would be the correct way to implement a second API call based on the result from the first API call? One of my Angular2 components has the following method. I tried with having a subscribe inside another subscribe on complete and the response from the second subscribe is always 'undefined'.

Edit based on suggestion from CozyAzure.

```
export interface Result {
  host: string;
  resourceUri: string;
  groupId?: string;
  resource?: any;
}

private curateResults(searchTerm: string, searchResults: SearchResults): Result[] {
    const results: Result[] = [];
    if (searchResults.results !== undefined && searchResults.results.length > 0) {
      searchResults.results.forEach((result: any) => {
        const processedSearchResult: Result = {
          host: result.origin.toString(),
          resourceUri: result.url.toString()
        };
        processedSearchResult.resource = undefined;
        processedSearchResult.groupId = undefined;
        this.bopsHttpService.getResourceData(processedSearchResult.host, processedSearchResult.resourceUri)
          .flatMap((resource: any) => {
            processedSearchResult.groupId = this.getGroupIdFromResource(resource, 'groupId');
            if (processedSearchResult.groupId === undefined) {
              const uriParts = processedSearchResult.resourceUri.split('/');
              const predicate = uriParts[uriParts.length - 2];
              if (predicate === 'group') {
                processedSearchResult.groupId = uriParts[uriParts.length - 1];
                return Observable.empty();
              } else {
                return this.bopsHttpService.getGroupRelation(processedSearchResult.resourceUri.split('/').pop());
              }
            } else {
              return Observable.empty();
            }
          })
          .subscribe((relation: any) => {
            if (relation !== undefined) {
              processedSearchResult.groupId = relation.objectId;
              console.log('Fetched Group ID: ', processedSearchResult.groupId);
            }
          });
        results.push(processedSearchResult);
      });
    }
  return results;
}
```

My http calls are as follows:

```
  public getGroupRelation(subjectId: string): Observable<Relation> {
    const path = `${this.bopsServiceUrl}/relation/${subjectId}/group`;
    const queryParameters = new URLSearchParams();
    queryParameters.set('at', new Date().toISOString());
    const options = new RequestOptions({
      headers: this.headers,
      search: queryParameters
    });
    return this.http.get(path, options)
      .map((response: Response) => response.json())
      .catch((error: any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error
        || 'BOPS Server error during get group relation Operation', 
          error.json()));
  }

  public getResourceData(host: string, resourceUri: string): Observable<any> {
    const path = host + resourceUri;
    const queryParameters = new URLSearchParams();
    queryParameters.set('at', new Date().toISOString());
    const options = new RequestOptions({
      headers: this.headers,
      search: queryParameters
    });
    return this.http.get(path, options)
      .map((response: Response) => response.json())
      .catch((error: any) => Observable.throw(error
        || 'BOPS Server error during Get Resource Data Operation'));
  }
```

Comment: Just to clarify, "processedSearchResult.groupId" is always undefined.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You will need to use `.flatMap()` if you want to chain your `Observables`. `flatMap()` is the same as `.then()` if you are thinking of the `Promise` way.

Do this instead:

```
this.bopsHttpService.getResourceData(processedSearchResult.host, processedSearchResult.resourceUri)
    .flatMap(() => {
        //check if groupId exist, or whatever your logic is
        if(hasGroupId){
            //groupId exist, proceed to call your second request
            return this.bopsHttpService.getGroupRelation(processedSearchResult.resourceUri.split('/').pop());
        }
        //groupId doesn't exist, return an empty Observable.
        return Observable.empty();

    })
    .subscribe((relation) => {
        if (relation !== undefined) {
            processedSearchResult.groupId = relation.objectId;
            console.log('Fetched Group ID: ', processedSearchResult.groupId);
        }
    })
```

Edit:

You can do any interventions inside your `flatMap()` callbacks. You can check if the `groupId` exist or not, only then you proceed to your next call. If it doesn't, simply returns an empty Observable using `Obersvable.empty()`.

Comment: Thank You @CozyAzure for the suggestion. Not sure if I follow this though. I have to make the second api call ONLY if the resource from first API call does not have the groupId.

Comment: Unfortunately, that did not work. processedSearchResult.groupId is still undefined.

Comment: Since I like the flatMap approach, I've updated my code and also updated the code in my question, with your suggestion. It looks like, while the second API call is being made, despite the result being successful, the UI is not waiting for the groupId inside subscribe.

Comment: @Rama if UI is not updating, probably you need an `async` pipe. https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe#!#examples

Comment: I didn't have to use the async pipe. I had a bug in my http call and once I fixed it, I got everything working again. Thanks for your help.