# form not recognizing passed property values

Tags: angular

In my `component.ts` file i am getting values into a property like so:

```
ngOnInit() {

        this.route.params.subscribe(params => {

            this.param = params['id'];
            this.pagesService.getEditPage(this.param).subscribe(page => {
                this.page = page;
            });

        });

    }
```

But in the template however, where i have a form with a text input and a textarea, that form is behaving as if it didn't have any values.

This is the form code:

```
<form novalidate #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="editPage(f)">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="">Title:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Title" name="title" value="{{page?.title}}" [(ngModel)]="title" #pageTitle="ngModel"
            minlength="2" required />
    </div>
    <div class="alert alert-danger" *ngIf="pageTitle.errors?.required && pageTitle.touched">
        Title is required.
    </div>
    <div class="alert alert-danger" *ngIf="pageTitle.errors?.minlength && pageTitle.touched">
        Minimum length is 2.
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="">Content:</label>
        <textarea class="form-control" name="content" placeholder="Content" cols="30" rows="10" [(ngModel)]="content" #pageContent="ngModel"
            minlength="5" required>{{ page?.content }}</textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="alert alert-danger" *ngIf="pageContent.errors?.required && pageContent.touched">
        Content is required.
    </div>
    <div class="alert alert-danger" *ngIf="pageContent.errors?.minlength && pageContent.touched">
        Minimum length is 5.
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <button class="btn btn-default" [disabled]="!f.valid">Edit page</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

When the form is displayed, the text input has the correct value but it is acting as if it didn't because validation for it kicks in, and the textarea does not show the true content at all, it shows the placeholder content (but when i inspect the textarea I can see its true content).

Is it because of some delay between getting the data and displaying the form or what? And how to remedy this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're misusing template-driven forms by using both `ngModel` and `value`. You're also missing the whole idea about Angular where your model defines the state of the app and templates are a way to decoratively express how to render that model to view.

You should not use `value` at all. With `[(ngModel)]="title"` you've correctly created two-way binding between the input control you've placed this directive on and the variable `title` from your class. When you want your input to be updated, you should **change the model, and view will be automatically updated for you**. So in your `.subscribe`, you should do the following.

```
this.title = page.title
```

Updating `title` will be noticed by Angular and because of `[ngModel]="title"`, that change will manifest itself into the view.

---

Unrelated to your question, but you're also misusing RxJS. Nested subscriptions are an anti-pattern and a potential memory leak. To [make dependent requests using RxJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45945846/how-to-make-2-dependent-http-request-in-angular-2/45945975#45945975), you would use the [`switchMap` operator](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-switchMap).

```
this.route.params
  .map(params => params.id) // or .pluck('id'), but you lose type safety
  .switchMap(params => this.pageService.getEditPage(params))
  .subscribe(page => this.page = page);
```

If you need to save the intermediate result of `params['id']` for some reason, you can use `.do` operator or simply save it before returning from the lambda inside `.switchMap`.