# call function before another on ngOnInit angular

Tags: angular, ngoninit

I want to call a function ta know the response data before calling the second function,this is in the same ngOnInit for angular project.Because I want to work with the response of the first function for the second function

Comment: Whats about async await?

Comment: Check this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45945846/how-to-make-2-dependent-http-request-in-angular-2).
It has an answer.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.